# Language decline due to chronic traumatic encephalopathy

Tags: neurology, cognitive-science, head-trauma, speech-pathology, traumatic-encephalopathy

I'm looking for references to studies on language decline due to progressing chronic traumatic encephalopathy (CTE). A preliminary search on google only gave me general info like "word loss, memory issues, mood swings" etc. I'm more interested in explicit studies that track some kind of metrics like sentence complexity or variety of words used. Put another way, suppose you wanted to detect CTE using language tests, which tests have been shown to be (moderately) effective?

Comment: Welcome to Health SE.  While speech (different from language) is used as part of a diagnosis for CTE, I'm not aware of a speech only effective method to detect any TBI or specifically CTE.  Did you come across [this chapter](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25701903) in your search?  As a small note, if you think you can handle primary research articles on health, PubMed is a great alternative to a general search engine like Google or DDG.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was truncated from the mobile ap. Do you want methods that could be used on sound only (like an audio recording)  or are methods that observe the creation of phonemes also allowed. By that I mean the motion of the body, so what a person would witness in person?

Comment: @AtlLED: Thanks for your help! The only relevant thing I saw was something for Alzheimers: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/pub/gh/Google-talk.pdf

Currently I'm mainly interested in just language abilities in written form. Thanks for the link and suggestions, I'll check them out.

Comment: Oh that's a completely different can of worms then. Hand written vs typed can even produce different results. Mind editing your question, to point out that you're interested in written forms of expression?

Comment: @Atl LED: sorry! I meant typed language.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic